# Utility partworths from dicrete choice experiments

Tags: r, marketing, conjoint-analysis, clogit, choice-modeling

Is it possible to estimate utility partworths from a discrete choice experiment (DCE)?

For example, if you construct a DCE using the R package `support.CEs` and analyse using the `clogit` function in the package `survival`, is there any way to calculate partworths?